# SAS SQL with the "Like" and '%___%'

Tags: sql, sas, sql-like

I have a dataset where I read in multiple sheets of an excel spreadsheet.  One of the variables (OrderDate) is in the "04-Aug-95" format, although when I print, it comes out "04AUG1995."

I'm trying to write code that will return the number (count) of orders in the first quarter of 1995.  However, the following code returns a list of every OrderDate in the data set and a Count of 830 (which is the total number of rows).  Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
proc sql;
select OrderDate, count(*) as Count
from Orders
where OrderDate LIKE '%JAN1995' OR '%FEB1995' OR '%MAR1995';
quit;
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause should be `WHERE OrderDate LIKE '%JAN1995' OR OrderDate LIKE '%FEB1995' OR OrderDate LIKE '%MAR1995';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either (in the where-clause):

```
Put(OrderDate, Date9.) like '%JAN1995' OR Put(OrderDate, Date9.) like '%FEB1995' OR Put(OrderDate, Date9.) like '%MAR1995'
```

Or:

```
Where Case When Put(OrderDate, Date9.) like '%JAN1995' Then 1
           When Put(OrderDate, Date9.) like '%FEB1995' Then 1
           When Put(OrderDate, Date9.) like '%MAR1995' Then 1
           Else 0
      End
```

Answer (score 0):

if your orderdate is stored in date then you could something like below and quarter one include jan feb and march

```
 Proc sql;
  select OrderDate, count(*) as Count
   from Orders
 where qtr(OrderDate) = 1 and year(OrderDate)=1995;
quit;
```

Comment: So it looks like your code pulls all first quarter observations but doesn't limit by year.  I wasn't aware of the "qtr" function so thanks for pointing that out.  I'm sure there's an easier way to do it but I ended doing it in two steps:

proc sql;
create table firstquarter as
select OrderDate
from Orders
where year(OrderDate)=1995;
run;
proc sql;
select count(*)
from firstquarter
where qtr(OrderDate)=1;
run;

Comment: you are right. we need to add year also. no need to make 2 different queries. just need to add end clause as in edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't mistake the format for the value.

The date in excel is stored as the number of days since 1/1/1970.  The date of `04-Aug-95` would have a value of 34915 in excel and is just formatted nicely to display to you.

SAS is similar in that date values and date formats are stored similarly.  The difference is that the epoch in SAS is 1/1/1960 (10 years earlier than excel).

Because date values are actually numeric values it doesn't really make sense to use a `like` statement on them.  You really want to select a date range using the where clause.  ie. `where OrderDate between '01jan1995'd and '31mar1995'd`.